# MVC (https) Internal site takes several seconds to load page in Chromium browers but < 1 second firefox and ie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, ssl, chromium, iis-10

I have a simple MVC application hosted internally by IIS 10 on a VM (windows server 2016). The initial page loads in 10 seconds in latest Chrome or Edge version (which is too slow I think) but takes less than 1 second in Firefox and IE. We have https redirect and SSL enabled. When you first click the web link in chrome, it will mostly say "establishing secure connection" but sometimes it says nothing. While its loading, you see the info icon in the browser (where the lock usually is). When you click on the (i) in Chrome for example, it says "Your connection to this site is not secure" then once it loads, this message goes away and you see the lock and that the certificate is valid. Why could this handshake take so much longer in chromium browsers compared to other browsers? Is there a setting? I am just a developer, not very savvy with the robustness of IIS settings (here, this is handled by server admin) nor am I familiar with certificate issues. If someone could point me in the right direction here it would be appreciated. I have spent hours trying various things (changing settings in chrome based on my research such as disabling tls or trying earlier versions of tls in the experimental features). I also tried disabling/enabling an https redirect in the web config and added a registry to my global.asax file. Adding site as whitelist, etc.  the list goes on.
Thanks for the info in advance,
Hydee V.

Comment: Even if a https cert is valid it may be revoked. There are multiple ways to check for a revoked certificate maybe Chromium uses one of them e.g. OCSP and something goes wrong? If you really want to understand what is going on use Wireshark and check what Chromium is doing in this 10 seconds delay.

Comment: Thanks for the info Robert, I’ll try that. Maybe it’s some kind of soft fail on a revocation.

Comment: Time to talk to your network/server administrators so that they can use tools like Wireshark to dive deeper into the TLS connections and locate the culprit. I don't think you alone can troubleshoot further.

Comment: Thanks Lex, we have discussed with them and they say this is normal response with SSL... but it bugs me.

Comment: If you can, provide some configuration files, maybe you can find clues from them.

Comment: Just an update... I tested and removed the certificate and redirect rules and site loads on http within a few ms. With that test, able to escalate it now.